# Run aspell on manpage

Tags: bash, manpage, aspell

I want use Aspell on man page but i have problem with word splitting.
I use man man | col -bx | aspell (...) but "man man | col -bx " return text with spitted words i.e:

```
"man formats and displays the on-line man-
ual pages. If you specify section, man on-
ly looks in that section of the manual."
```

So Aspell return this words as wrong.

Any ideas how switch it off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to format the man pages without hyphenation. This should do it:

```
 groff -mtty-char -Tutf8 -man -rHY=0 /usr/share/man/man1/man.1
```

Alternatively tell it the page is so wide that it never hyphenates:

```
 groff -mtty-char -Tutf8 -man -rLL=1000000 /usr/share/man/man1/man.1
```

And now some explanation, so you know where to find this stuff. `man` formats pages with `nroff`, which is just a script around `groff`. You can find out what that does with:

```
sh -x $(which nroff) -man /usr/share/man/man1/man.1
```

This in turn will spit out a `groff` command similar to the one above. You can then find out what groff does internally with `-V`:

```
groff -mtty-char -Tutf8 -man -V /usr/share/man/man1/man.1
```

...and find out about the hyphenation flags I used with

```
man groff_man
```