# Disable groff hyphenation at the command line

Tags: groff, troff

I am using the program `groff` to format text. groff is hyphenating words and breaking them onto multiple lines. I would not like it to do that.

The [manual outlines methods for disabling hyphenation](https://www.gnu.org/software/groff/manual/html_node/Manipulating-Hyphenation.html). However, I can't figure out how to invoke `.hn` at the command line. Is there a way to pass command line flags to groff to disable hyphenation?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 4):

Taken from the awesome [Run aspell on manpage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22712319/run-aspell-on-manpage#22713606).

You should pass the HY register with the value 0 with the `-rHY=0` command line flag.

Command line flags to `groff` are documented via `man groff_man`. This manual page is available in Ubuntu/Debian through the `groff` package (not included with the `groff-base` package, which *does* include the `groff` binary).

The value 0 of `HY` is actually not explicitly documented as a way to disable indentation, but it seems to work!

Comment: Additionally, passing -rHY=14 gets back the less agressive hyphenation of version 1.22.3.

Comment: Thanks for this.  For some reason putting `.HY 0` in the document itself seems to have no effect, at least using the `.ms` macroset, but this works.

Answer (score 1):

For what it's worth, the hyphenation difference was appearing because my colleague was using groff version 1.22.3 and I was using groff 1.22.4. 1.22.3 does not use as aggressive hyphenation.

I suspect that there is no way to control hyphenation at the command line.